# CSS tabs with jQuery: displaying just the content of current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have this HTML file with some CSS styles, now I am trying to create vertical tabs but when the page loads all the content is being displayed then if I select any particular tab only content of that tab is display but I am just worried when the page. How come all the tab content is being displayed? Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
<head>
<title>Follow me!</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    ul.tabs {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px; /*--Set height of tabs--*/
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;*/
    float:left;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;

    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff; /*--Gives the bevel look with a 1px white border inside the list item--*/
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  { /*--Makes sure that the active tab does not listen to the hover properties--*/
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; /*--Makes the active tab look like it's connected with its content--*/
}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left; width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.spacing {
    margin-left:90px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $("ul.tabs li:first-child a").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content #link1").css("display", "block"); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li a").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(".tab_content div").css("display","none");

        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab


        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
</script>


</head>
<body>

            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="#link1" class="tab_content">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link2" class="tab_content">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link3" class="tab_content">Link3</a></li>

            </ul>
        <div class="tab_content spacing">
            <div id="link1">
                <p>Link1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="link2">
                <p>Link2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="link3">
                <p>Link3</p>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your css:

```
div.spacing > div {
    display: none;
}
```

This hides all the divs that are children of the div with the class `spacing`.

Or, for better 'graceful degredation', hide them in your `document.ready` function:

```
$('div.spacing > div').hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

you might want to use :

```
$(".tab_content div")live(,"ready",function(){
.... hide tabs that are not link1
})
```

or as your tabs need javascript to work you can hide them at start and show the first one when ready (just don't forget your noscript tag)